# Roles.AddUserToRole finds different userId given the same username

Tags: ef-code-first, roleprovider

I am creating some data in the seed method. I am creating a few users with a few permissions (roles)

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MibContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
Roles.CreateRole(Constants.Roles.Administrator);
Roles.CreateRole(Constants.Roles.ContentManager);
Roles.CreateRole(Constants.Roles.KeyAccountManager);
```

I then have variable for the username (to avoid any typo possibility)

```
var adminusername = "admin@domain.com";
var userusername = "user@domain.com";
```

I create the Userprofile record via EF and the UnitOfWork Pattern

```
var admin = new UserProfile
        {
            FirstName = "Admin",
            LastName = "Account",
            UserName = adminusername
        };
unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(admin);
unitOfWork.Save();
```

Then create the user Membership account, and assign roles:

```
WebSecurity.CreateAccount(adminusername, "123456");
WebSecurity.CreateAccount(userusername, "123456");

Roles.AddUserToRole(userusername, Constants.Roles.Administrator);
Roles.AddUserToRole(userusername, Constants.Roles.KeyAccountManager);
```

The last roles command causes the error, Foreign Key Violation between UsersInRoles and UserProfile. Which is very strange since it can map a role to the first user (which was the admin user first time around, but wanted to see if it could create a permission for that user, which it does)

I then removed the foreign key constraint to see what was going on, and it put a 3 in there. Testing by repeating but adding a 4th role, it seems that the (username, role) parameters are the wrong way around!?!? The new role has Id=4, and on repeating the test, that is what it put in the UserId column.

```
RoleId  UserId
2        1
2        4
NULL     NULL
```

Roles are configured :

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" 
         type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: SQL Profiling shows this command: 
INSERT INTO webpages_UsersInRoles VALUES (4,1); 
Which is the order I put into the method, but the table is created with the ROLE first, not the user. If they had put the field names in, it would all work nicely.

Comment: Nice that you left this question here and answered it. I am after 4 hours of hunting for why AddUserToRole would throw key violation. It would be nice if you could update title of question with key violation, because that was what I search first for like "AddUsersToRole throws key violation exception" or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of fields in the webpages_UsersInRole table is obviously very important.

I looked at the mapping to see what was there, and the relationship (many -> many) was defined on the ROLES table side. I swapped the mapping to the Users side and it is now working correctly. Here is the mapping I used on the UserProfile object.

```
 // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.webpages_Roles)
            .WithMany(t => t.UserProfiles)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            });
```

Really, the Role Provider should not assume on the order of columns and should specify their names. At least I can still use the default functionality by amending the mapping this way. This is pretty poor SQL:

```
INSERT INTO webpages_UsersInRoles VALUES (4,1);
```